# pass method agument to local instance object for filter list

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, conceptual

I would like to convert argument in prent method to filter list result with filter of an local instance object.

That is what I would like approximatively for the concept

```
def get_fields(path, editable=True): # If only editable (or opposite)
    return list([f.name for f in fields(path) if f.editable]) # Do filter
def get_fields(path, required=True): # If only required (or opposite)
    return list([f.name for f in fields(path) if f.required]) # Do filter

def get_fields(path): # If all
    return list([f.name for f in fields(path)])
```

This is what i do actualy

```
def get_fields_editable(path):
    return list(f.name for f in fields(path) if f.editable]))

def get_fields_required(path):
    return list(f.name for f in fields(path) if f.required]))

def get_fields(path):
    return list(f.name for f in fields(path)]))
```

Comment: Change `if f.editable` to `if f.editable==editable`?

Comment: Do you need to handle both `editable` and `required` being True?

Comment: Yes but don't need method and conditial if statement to get all fields. @Rawing i don't want that because if it's  None I get no data. Methods result are strict Boolean

Comment: I'm still a little confused. :) I _think_ you want to be able to call `get_fields(path, editable=True)` to get a list of `f.name`s for all `f` where `f.editable` is `True`, and if you call `get_fields(path, editable=False)` you want a list of `f.name`s for all `f` where `f.editable` is `False`. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, if I understand your last comment, you will only call `get_fields` with (at most) one of `editable` or `required`, not both.

Comment: Yes this is a combination of 3 methods to get one in differents cases. path is obligatory and editable or required optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`operator.attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter) to create a suitable filtering function from the keyword arg name and the associated value.

To demonstrate this code I created a simple `Test` object, and a `fields` function.

```
from operator import attrgetter

def get_fields(path, **kwargs):
    # Create the filter function
    # Assumes there will only ever be at most a single keyword arg
    if kwargs:
        key, val = kwargs.popitem()
        func = attrgetter(key)
        filter_func = func if val else lambda obj: not func(obj)
    else:
        filter_func = lambda obj: True

    return [f.name for f in fields(path) if filter_func(f)]

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name, editable, required):
        self.name = name
        self.editable = editable
        self.required = required

def fields(path):
    return [
        Test(path + '_a', False, False),
        Test(path + '_b', False, True),
        Test(path + '_c', True, False),
        Test(path + '_d', True, True),
    ]

print(get_fields('none'))
print(get_fields('edfalse', editable=False))
print(get_fields('edtrue', editable=True))
print(get_fields('reqfalse', required=False))
print(get_fields('reqtrue', required=True))
```

**output**

```
['none_a', 'none_b', 'none_c', 'none_d']
['edfalse_a', 'edfalse_b']
['edtrue_c', 'edtrue_d']
['reqfalse_a', 'reqfalse_c']
['reqtrue_b', 'reqtrue_d']
```

---

Here's a new version that handles multiple keywords. Only items that pass all of the filter tests are returned. I've changed the test object names slightly and added a `print` call to `get_fields` to make it easier to see what's going on. This code works on both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from operator import attrgetter

# Return items that pass any of the filters
def get_fields_any(path, **kwargs):
    seq = fields(path)
    print('KW', kwargs)
    result = set()
    if kwargs:
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            # Create the filter function
            func = attrgetter(key)
            filter_func = func if val else lambda obj: not func(obj)
            # Apply it
            result.update(filter(filter_func, seq))
    else:
        result = seq

    return [f.name for f in result]

# Only return items that pass all filters
def get_fields(path, **kwargs):
    seq = fields(path)
    print('KW', kwargs)
    if kwargs:
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            # Create the filter function
            func = attrgetter(key)
            filter_func = func if val else lambda obj: not func(obj)
            # Apply it
            seq = list(filter(filter_func, seq))
    return [f.name for f in seq]

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, name, editable, required):
        self.name = name
        self.editable = editable
        self.required = required

    def __repr__(self):
        fmt = 'Test({name}, {editable}, {required})'
        return fmt.format(**self.__dict__)

def fields(path):
    return [
        Test(path + ':FF', False, False),
        Test(path + ':FT', False, True),
        Test(path + ':TF', True, False),
        Test(path + ':TT', True, True),
    ]

print(get_fields('__'))
print(get_fields('_F', required=False))
print(get_fields('_T', required=True))
print(get_fields('F_', editable=False))
print(get_fields('T_', editable=True))
print()

print(get_fields('FF', editable=False, required=False))
print(get_fields('FT', editable=False, required=True))
print(get_fields('TF', editable=True, required=False))
print(get_fields('TT', editable=True, required=True))
```

**output**

```
KW {}
['__:FF', '__:FT', '__:TF', '__:TT']
KW {'required': False}
['_F:FF', '_F:TF']
KW {'required': True}
['_T:FT', '_T:TT']
KW {'editable': False}
['F_:FF', 'F_:FT']
KW {'editable': True}
['T_:TF', 'T_:TT']

KW {'editable': False, 'required': False}
['FF:FF']
KW {'editable': False, 'required': True}
['FT:FT']
KW {'editable': True, 'required': False}
['TF:TF']
KW {'editable': True, 'required': True}
['TT:TT']
```

Note that this code can handle any number of keywords, not just two.

---

I've also included an experimental function `get_fields_any` which returns the objects that pass *any* of the filters. It uses a set `result` to accumulate the matching objects, so it doesn't preserve order. Also, putting objects that don't define `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods into sets (or using them as `dict` keys) is risky. See the [`__hash__ docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) for details.

Comment: It work fine! That is exactely what I want! Can it work with twice? print(get_fields('reqtrue', required=True, editable=True)) I think that only work with first kwargs

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten When I asked earlier "you will only call `get_fields` with (at most) one of `editable` or `required`, not both." you replied "Yes". So that's why I wrote the code like this. (In fact, I didn't start writing the code until I got the answer to that question). I _can_ modify it to handle multiple keywords, but I need some time to think about how to do it efficiently.

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten Another way to approach this is to let `get_fields` take a list (or other iterable) of objects as its primary arg instead of `path`. So you could do, for example, `seq = fields(path); newseq = get_fields(seq, editable=False);  newseq = get_fields(newseq, required=False)`

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten Also, if multiple args are given, should the filter return objects that pass _all_ conditions or should it return objects that pass _any_ condition. Eg, should `print(get_fields('', editable=True, required=True))` just return `['_d']`, or should it return `['_b', '_c', '_d']` ?

Comment: yes in accordance to your exemple and that I want `print(get_fields('', editable=True, required=True))` must return `['_d']` and oposite `print(get_fields('', editable=False, required=False))` return `['_a']`